# Problems spawing a simple object

Tags: gazebo-1.3, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As I had much problems with gazebo under fuerte I decieded to try out groovy with gazebo 1.3. But it won´t spawn a simple object.

```
    Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
  Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.2.4
[ INFO] [1364762386.117130304]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 192.168.2.4
[ INFO] [1364762387.522566147]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:159] No <database> tag in the model database manifest.xml found here[http://gazebosim.org/models/]
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:211] Unable to download model manifests
```

The following command keeps running:

```
 rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file object.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model my_object
[INFO] [WallTime: 1364763933.932859] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
```

I tried to convert the empy.world with gzsdf tool but I could not locate the tool..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2152/problems-spawing-a-simple-object/) by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

make sure you sourced the setup.bash file:

```
/<path>/gazebo$ source setup.bash
```

then run in a terminal:

```
$ rosrun gazebo gzsdf convert /<path>/your.sdf
```

or

```
/<path>/gazebo$ ./gazebo/bin/gzsdf convert /<path>/your.sdf
```

(you may need sudo rights for converting the `empty.world` file, or you could just create another one in a different package)

!!!!Update!!!!

to spawn use:

```
$ gzfactory spawn -f /<path>/model.sdf -m model_name -x 1 -y 1 -z 2 -R 0 -P 0 -Y 0
```

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-04-01**:
I can find the plugin now but I can't convert the empty world. That does not seem to be the problem.  I think spawn_model does not work anymore?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-01**:
and why cant you convert the world file? that should also work, did you try it with sudo?

**Comment by [Davinci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/108/davinci/) on 2013-04-01**:
spawning works now thanks. Weird that I also had to source the gazebo setup,bash, this was not necessary in fuerte.